# Write a dataframe into an Excel file withour erasing old tabs

Tags: python

I have an Excel file which has 5 tabs (Let us assume A,B,C,D,E). I want to write a dataframe into tab 'C'.

I tried to do this using Pandas using the .to_excel function, but the final workbook only has tab 'C'. The other tabs got erased. I want to keep them intact. Also tried Excel Writer and Openpyxl but same results.

Here is the snippet I used (latest_file1 has the path of my file from which I wamt the latest file from my folder)

marketdf is my dataframe

```
import glob
import os
list_of_files1 = glob.glob(r"C:\Data\Project\Test\File*.xlsx")
latest_file1 = max(list_of_files1, key=os.path.getctime)    
marketdf.to_excel(latest_file1,sheet_name='RAW Data')
```

Comment: add your full code

Comment: Added the snippet.

Comment: It does not support update but write only. I usually read everything into an array of dataframes (or different dataframes) and write at one go.